# Flex AdvancedDataGrid listItems strange behaviour

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I have the following XML, that is the dataprovider (as a Hierarchicaldata) of an Advanced DataGrid:

```
public var reqData:XML = <root>
  <Requirement ID="REQ-GEN-0.1" title="exigence gen 1" description="blabla 01" testable="true"/>
  <RequirementSet ID="GUI REQ">
    <Requirement ID="REQ-GUI-1.1" title="exigence ihm 1" description="blabla 11" testable="true"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-GUI-1.2" title="exigence ihm 2" description="blabla 12" testable="false"/>
  </RequirementSet>
  <RequirementSet ID="PERF REQ">
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.1" title="exigence perf 1" description="blabla 21" testable="true"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.2" title="exigence perf 2" description="blabla 22" testable="false"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.3" title="exigence perf 3" description="blabla 23" testable="true"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.4" title="exigence perf 4" description="blabla 24" testable="false"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.5" title="exigence perf 5" description="blabla 25" testable="false"/>
    <Requirement ID="REQ-PERF-2.6" title="exigence perf 6" description="blabla 26" testable="false"/>
  </RequirementSet>
  <RequirementSet ID="BUS REQ">
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 1 REQ">
      <Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.1.1" title="exigence bus 1" description="blabla 311" testable="false"/>
      <Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.1.2" title="exigence bus 2" description="blabla 312" testable="true"/>
    </RequirementSet>
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 2 REQ">
      <Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.2.1" title="exigence bus3" description="blabla 321" testable="true"/>
    </RequirementSet>
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 3 REQ"/>
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 4 REQ">
        <Requirement ID="REQ-BUS-3.4.1" title="exigence bus4" description="blabla 341" testable="false"/>
    </RequirementSet>
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 5 REQ"/>
    <RequirementSet ID="BUS 6 REQ"/>
  </RequirementSet>
</root>;
```

And here is the AdvancedDataGrid part:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="reqADGtest" displayItemsExpanded="true"
                                             width="95%" height="75%" horizontalCenter="0" 
                                             contentBackgroundAlpha="0.0" chromeColor="0xdbeaff"
                                             openDuration="500" dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true"
                                             dragMoveEnabled="true" editable="true"
                                             variableRowHeight="true" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto">
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@ID" headerText="ID"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@title" headerText="Titre"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@testable" headerText="Testable"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@description" headerText="Description"
                                                           editorUsesEnterKey="true"
                                                           wordWrap="true"/>
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

The problem is that when I look at the listItems' length of the AdvancedDataGrid, it is 19 at the creation, and then 16 that is totally wrong (22 items). I want to access to some items and I can't which is really annoying. Is it a bug or something?

**NOTE:**

To access items by rowIndex and columnIndex I'm doing the following:

```
var advancedDataGridListData:AdvancedDataGridListData = 
                IDropInListItemRenderer(listItems[event.rowIndex][event.columnIndex]).listData 
                as AdvancedDataGridListData;

IHierarchicalCollectionView(dataProvider).getChildren(
                advancedDataGridListData.item)
```

**EDITED 23/02/2012**

I tested your solution with event.item but unfortunatly this item was always null and I didn't understand why. So I looked deeper into the source code of AdvancedDataGridBaseEx and I found that this is a part of the Adobe source code):

```
// send event to create the new one
        var advancedDataGridEvent:AdvancedDataGridEvent =
            new AdvancedDataGridEvent(AdvancedDataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_BEGINNING, false, true);
        // ITEM_EDIT events are cancelable
        advancedDataGridEvent.columnIndex = columnIndex;
        advancedDataGridEvent.dataField = _columns[columnIndex].dataField;
        advancedDataGridEvent.rowIndex = rowIndex;
        dispatchEvent(advancedDataGridEvent);
```

You can see that the event.item is never filled!!!! Thanks Adobe... I will try your other solution then I give you feedback.

**LAST EDIT**

I solved my problem by using in my custom datagrid:

```
var xmlNode:XML = this.selectedItem as XML;
```

Comment: I'm confused... shouldn't you be looking at the dataProvider, I believe the listItems keeps track of the renderers which are dynamically created and recycled, hence the changing count (if you scale the app so there's less area to draw you should see an even lower number in listItems I believe).

Comment: The problem is that I have to access to items by rowIndex and columnIndex. I have an ITEM_EDIT_BEGINNING event and I want to filter the items that can be edited. The event just returns rowIndex and columnIndex and I thought it was the way to access items:
    var advancedDataGridListData:AdvancedDataGridListData = 
    IDropInListItemRenderer(listItems[event.rowIndex][event.columnIndex]).listData 
    as AdvancedDataGridListData;

Comment: That part should work out fine are you getting null object references when using that code or are you just worried about the changing size of listItems?  To iterate across the entire collection just use dataProvider or dataProvider.source; the dataProvider should stay consistent with regard to length aside from if a filterFunction is applied.  listItems will change depending on what is shown on screen (and a couple of extra offscreen renderers that are made to basically give it some read ahead so rows just off screen are ready for display in advance).

Comment: The problem is: I can't access to data by row and column with the dataprovider. And as my listItems' length is 16 (and not 22), I can't access to the last items. When I click on one of the last items I get an error cause listItems[event.rowIndex][event.columnIndex] doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

dataProvider.getChildren(event.item)

based on reading here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGridBaseEx.html#event:itemEditBeginning

Alternatively maybe this method would help (though it's protected so you may need to do a "monkey patch" to change the access control modifier from protected to public:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGridBaseEx.html#absoluteToVisibleIndices()

I think on the event.rowIndex and event.columnIndex it's essentially giving you absolute values but the listItems has it based on what's currently visible rather than the absolute positions.  Not a direct answer I know but it's very late here.

Comment: Solved!! Thanks! I just get the Item by using: var xmlNode:XML = this.selectedItem as XML;

Comment: No problem glad you were able to figure it out and I didn't have to try and dig into the ADG code myself again :)